# Generate Key for signing within nodejs

Tags: node.js, cryptography, signing

I have what seems to be a rather simple problem, but I never had to deal with cryptography in nodejs before.
I want to implement a system which generates a new keypair about every 4 months, which are used for signing and verifying a generated result.
This is my current code:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const algorithm = 'RSA-SHA512';
const sign = crypto.createSign(algorithm);
const verify = crypto.createVerify(algorithm);
const base64 = 'base64';
const keyDir = './keys/';

const validator = {};

validator.check = function(dataArray, signature, date){
  verify.update(Buffer.from(dataArray));
  return verify.verify(getPublicKey(date), signature);
};

validator.sign = function(dice){
  sign.update(Buffer.from(dice));
  return sign.sign(getPrivateKey(), base64);//Error happens here
};

validator.getPublicKey = function(date){
  date = toDateObject(date);
  for(current of getFilesDescending()){
    if(fileNameToDate(current).getMilliseconds() <= date.getMilliseconds()){
    const prefix = '-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----';
    const suffix = '-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----';
      return prefix + fs.readFileSync(keyDir + fileName, 'utf8').split('\n')[0] + suffix;
    }
  }
}

function fileNameToDate(fileName){
  const array = fileName.split("-");
  return new Date(array[0], parseInt(array[1]) - 1);
}

function getPrivateKey(){
  const file = getFilesDescending()[0];
  if(!file || monthDiff(new Date(), fileNameToDate(file)) > 4){
    generateKeys();
    return getPrivateKey();
  }
  const prefix = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';
  const suffix = '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';
  return prefix + fs.readFileSync(keyDir + file, 'utf8').split('\n')[1] + suffix;
}

function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months;
}

function getFilesDescending(){
  return fs.readdirSync(keyDir).sort().reverse();
}

function getMonth(date){
  return ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)
}

function generateKeys(){
  const fileName = getFileName();
  if(!fs.existsSync(fileName)){
    const diffieHell = crypto.createDiffieHellman(1024);//TODO change this value to a stronger one
    diffieHell.generateKeys(base64);
    fs.writeFileSync(fileName, diffieHell.getPublicKey(base64) + '\n' + diffieHell.getPrivateKey(base64));
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function getFileName(){
  const now = new Date();
  return keyDir + now.getFullYear() + '-' + getMonth(now);
}

function toDateObject(date){
  return Date.from(date) || new Date();
}

module.exports = validator;
```

Basically whenever the sign method is invoked, the code checks if there is a keypair fiñe which was generated within the last 4 months and if it is not generate such a keypair and use that one. The data param is a ISO string which is returned by Date.toISOString().
I'm getting the following error: `Error: error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long`.
2 Questions: I'm probaly doing something really obvious wrong here, what should I do instead?
And should I dump my attempt entirely and use HTTPS certificates instead?
I'd prefer not to because this makes local testing a lot harder.

Comment: It's not possible to use node's crypto module to generate RSA keys. It simply doesn't provide that functionality. DH and RSA are not the same or even compatible as in achieve similar things. You would need to find another module that does this.

Comment: *"And should I dump my attempt entirely and use HTTPS certificates instead?"* - You haven't said what you're signing and why. It's impossible to answer. If HTTPS solves your problem, use it.