# NodeJS Generate Valid PEM keys for Signing and Verifying messages

Tags: node.js, ssl, pem

### Context

From the NodeJS documentation on TLS/SSL for Node v10.9.0 (2018-AUG)

https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_ssl_concepts

```
openssl genrsa -out ryans-key.pem 2048
```

Will produce:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
base64 encoded magic here...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Which I can then successfully use the `Sign` class to cryptographically sign a message:

https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_sign

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');

sign.update('some data to sign');

const privateKey = `Insert magic value from above`;
console.log(sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64'));
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const dhke = crypto.createDiffieHellman(2048);
dhke.generateKeys();
const private_pem = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
${dhke.getPrivateKey('base64')}
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`;
console.log(private_pem);

const sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
sign.update('some data to sign');

const signature = sign.sign(private_pem, 'base64');
console.log(signature);
```

Getting the following error:

```
Error: error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long
    at Sign.sign (internal/crypto/sig.js:84:26)
...
```

### The Question

How do I use the `crypto` library in NodeJS to achieve what `openssl` command line tool is performing (or another NPM module) to create a valid PEM formatted public/private key-pair which is required by the `Sign` class?

### Similar unresolved questions

- [Generate Key for signing within nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363705/generate-key-for-signing-within-nodejs)

## Solution

Here is the start to finish working solution thanks to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173811/622276) from [JacobTDC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8340438/jacobtdc) where NodeJS v10.12.0 added this feature.

```
const crypto = require('crypto'); const sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');

sign.update('some data to sign');

// $ openssl genrsa -out ryans-key.pem 2048 
// const privateKey = `Insert magic value from above`;

const { generateKeyPairSync } = require('crypto'); 
const { publicKey, privateKey } = generateKeyPairSync('rsa', 
{   modulusLength: 2048,  // the length of your key in bits   
    publicKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'spki',       // recommended to be 'spki' by the Node.js docs
      format: 'pem'   
    },   
    privateKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'pkcs8',      // recommended to be 'pkcs8' by the Node.js docs
      format: 'pem',
      //cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',   // *optional*
      //passphrase: 'top secret' // *optional*   
  } 
}); 
console.log(privateKey); 
console.log(sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64'));
```

Comment: I'm wondering if this could be further extended to generate a self-signed certificate using pure Node?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of Node.js v10.12.0, you can use [crypto.generateKeyPair](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypair_type_options_callback) and [crypto.generateKeyPairSync](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypairsync_type_options).

I have provided an example from the Node.js docs below (with added comments):

```
const { generateKeyPairSync } = require('crypto');
const { publicKey, privateKey } = generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
  modulusLength: 4096,  // the length of your key in bits
  publicKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'spki',       // recommended to be 'spki' by the Node.js docs
    format: 'pem'
  },
  privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'pkcs8',      // recommended to be 'pkcs8' by the Node.js docs
    format: 'pem',
    cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',   // *optional*
    passphrase: 'top secret' // *optional*
  }
});
```

Comment: When trying to use the generated certificates: `Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line`, yet both have start and end lines.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is DH keys are not RSA keys and not fully compatible.

Unfortunately, node does not have the ability to produce real RSA pairs via the `crypto` module either which is a bit disappointing. You'll need to either interact with your local `openssl` library to do this, or a third party module depending on your requirements.

As far as third party modules, [`keypair`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keypair) is a simple library which will work in your given situation

```
const keypair = require('keypair');
const keys: { private: string, public: string } = keypair({ bits : 2056 }); // 2056 is the default but added for example
```

I've also found good results with [`openpgpjs`](https://openpgpjs.org/) which is much more featured while also focusing on being a platform agnostic module. If you're looking at doing crypto in the browser as well as node, then this might be a good option.